# Linux: Piping data turns regular dataflow choppy

Tags: python, linux, pipe

I am on Linux (Ubuntu). I have a c program that handles serial communication with an arduino giving me sensor readings many times a second printed onto console. The incoming data flow is pretty regular. I also have a small python program that should take this data and work with it. For testing the python file is just print(input()) in an endless loop. If I then pipe my serial communication into my python program via:

```
.sercom | python3 main.py
```

The dataflow that I get out turns very choppy, the lines come in batches with small pauses inbetween. Is this just how piping works? Is there something I can do to turn the flow smoother again? If not, what kind of alternatives could I use to get smooth data flow between my programs?

Edit:
Here is how to reproduce what I mean: Create two python files

pipe_out.py:

```
from time import sleep
for n in range(0, 100000):
    print(n, 'testing lines out of 100000')
    sleep(0.001)
```

pipe_in.py:

```
for i in range(0, 100000):
  print(input())
```

and then compare the console output of

```
python3 pipe_out.py
```

vs

```
python3 pipe_out.py | python3 pipe_in.py
```

The output from the first comes one very smooth, while the output from the second comes choppy, in blocks of ~500 lines

Comment: Line-based buffering? In any case, for a proper question here, please extract and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @UlrichEckhardt for hint regarding Line-based buffering. With this I was able to fix it. The problem is indeed that the normal linux piping uses line buffering. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) I found a thread that deals piping without line buffer via the expect package, which solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that pipes use a line-buffer. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)
is a post that deals with piping without line-buffer. The gist is to use the expect package and add unbuffer in front of your piping command.